# Express bodyParser cannot parse data coming from Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, express

I've created a server app using Node and Express 4, while the front-end is built using jQuery.
I've got an Ajax call sending some data using POST to the server:

```
$.ajax({
     cache: false,
     type: 'POST',
     url: Config.API_ENDPOINT_REGISTRATION,
     dataType : 'json',
     data: info,
     success: this.successHandler.bind(this)
 });
```

Everything is behaving as expected in all modern browsers, except IE8 and IE9.

To make the Ajax call possible from jQuery I had to use the XDomainRequest script provided here: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest
Before adding this script the call wasn't happening.

The issue now is that the request.body I get in Express is always empty if the data is coming from IE8/IE9.

I suppose something is going on with the bodyParser unable to parse the data received from IE8/IE9: the request.body is always empty.

I've been trying to resolve this issue for an entire day now, with no success.

Any idea or something that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after digging a bit more into this issue (a while ago) I noticed that the `content-type` header was empty on both IE8 and IE9.

Because empty is not the default value, I've checked if something was interfering with my XDomainRequest settings, and I found that the [jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) was altering the xdr.contentType setting it to "" (empty).

The solution I created for this issue is an Express.js middleware to set/override the content-type header for the requests to a specific route. Here is a usage example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var registrationController = require('./controllers/registrationController');

server.use( '/registration', contentTypeOverride({
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}));
server.use( bodyParser.json() );
server.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post( '/registration', registrationController.index );

app.listen( 3000 );
```

You can find the middleware here: [express-content-type-override](https://github.com/rbartoli/express-content-type-override)

Answer (score 2):

In IE9 the [XDomainRequest doesn't set a content-type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx), which bodyparser requires in order to read the request body as json.

I got around this by setting the content-type explicitly before passing the request through to body parser, like so:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // IE9 doesn't set headers for cross-domain ajax requests
    if(typeof(req.headers['content-type']) === 'undefined'){
        req.headers['content-type'] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    }
    next();
})
.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: As specified in my previous answer, I've created a middleware for Express that set's the content type to any value you want: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-content-type-override